# how to resolve the problem export switch in react probraming

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports:

I have replace the Switch with Routes then another problem happen which is thie export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: